# show that $I, T, T^2, ..., T^k$ are linear dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, independence

I am learning linear algebra and new to it. I can not solve this problem. I think it has a trick that I don't know.

> for T(a linear map), $T:V\rightarrow V$ and every $v$ in $V$ the $v, T(v), T^2(v), ..., T^k(v)$ are **linearly dependent** where $k$ is a natural number $\leq \dim(V)$.
>
> show that $I, T, T^2, ..., T^k$ are linearly dependent

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is T? A matrix?

Comment: @H_1317 yes, T is actually "T:V→V". unfortunately, I've asked the question wrong!  it must be actually "T(v)s are dependent prove Ts are dependent". I mean both "independent"s should be "dependent".

when I saw guys were answering the question I didn't edit that and just accept the answer.

Comment: Can u edit your question identifying what T is, and the proper wording for any other errors please? Also what vector space u believe T is in (a matrix space?) thanks

Comment: @H_1317, sorry if I'm not so familiar but I think "T:V→V" is a  linear map no? where T must be a matrix, am I wrong? T is a map from V to V where V can be any vector space I think.

Comment: Just press the edit button underneath ur question...

Comment: If $a_i T^i = 0$ is a linear combination of the $T^i,$ choose some $v$ for which the $T^i(v)$ are linearly independent vectors (you need to assume that only one such $v$ exists, not that every $v$ (which, by the way cannot be) satisfies it) and then conclude all scalars are zero.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $a_1T+...+a_kT^k=0$. Let $x\neq 0$, $a_1T(x)+...+a_kT^k(x)=0$, this implies that $a_1=..=a_k=0$ since $T(x),...T^k(x)$ are linearly independent. It results that $T,....T^k$ is linearly independent.

Remark, you have to suppose for every $v\neq 0$, $T(v),...,T^k(v)$ is linearly independent since it is not true for $v=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

Suppose that $T,T^2,\dots, T^k$ are not linearly independent. Then,  there exists $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_k \in \mathbb R$ not all zero, such that :

$$\lambda_1T + \lambda_2T^2 + \cdots + \lambda_kT^k = 0$$

Comment: such that what!?

Comment: @Peyman Fixed. Thanks.